# kotlin project can't be build in gradle

Tags: java, intellij-idea, gradle, build, kotlin

I have a java project that write in kotlin ,i use intelliJ IDEA to develop this project.  I have trouble on the dependencies setting (multiple project). I already read lot of examples , but I can't find the workaround , here is my dependencies setting code,
it can be build in java class correctly , but the kotlin class will get lot of error 'Unresolved reference' . Is that any wrong about my setting or gradle is not suitable with kotlin .

PS : when i only build core project , build process will successful , but build at test project will get the reference unresolved error

```
allprojects {
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'kotlin'
group 'testProject'
version '1.0'
}



subprojects{
apply plugin:  'java'
apply plugin: 'kotlin'
def defaultEncoding = 'UTF-8'
compileJava.options.encoding = defaultEncoding
sourceCompatibility = 1.8
targetCompatibility = 1.8

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    mavenLocal()
}

dependencies {

    // Kotlin
    compile "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
    compile "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-reflect:$kotlin_version"
    compile "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:$kotlin_version"
}
}
project(':test') {
dependencies {
    compile project(':core')
    compile project(':testTwo')
}

project(':testTwo'){
dependencies{
    compile project(':core')
}
```

setting.gradle

```
include 'test','testTwo','core'
```

Comment: What's exactly unresolved? Do you have all kotlin dependencies [configured](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/using-gradle.html)?

Comment: when kotlin class (test project)reference from core project (kotlin class) , get the  'Unresolved reference'  at gradle build.

Comment: yes, i  done the configure.

Comment: I don't see a dependency on the Kotlin standard library: `compile "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:$kotlin_version"`

Comment: i supplement some code

Comment: is a problem solved?

Comment: the problem not yet get solved

Answer (score 0):

The kotlin-gradle-plugin is not a dependency of your subprojects, it is a dependency of the buildscript itself.

Follow the instructions on [Plugin and Versions](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/using-gradle.html#plugin-and-versions)

Comment: yes , i have classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version" in buildscript dependencies.